# I cannot make a new file or delete files on Atom using Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, atom-editor

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux and built a web server. And I am also using Atom installed on Windows.

If I create a new file in Atom, the file isn't shown on the Bash shell on Ubuntu.

And then if I try to create the file on the shell, it says:

> “The file exists.”

Then I cannot even delete the file, just showed me "Input-output error".

Is there anything wrong with the way I am using Atom and Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Is there any solution to these problems?